# magmi import group price

Tags: magento-1.7, magmi

```
Can anyone tell me how to import Group price

I tries to a plugin group price importer as link given below
```

> https://github.com/tim-bezhashvyly/magmi-grouped-price-plugin
>
> It says to add the column `group_price:customer_group` in csv.

However it is not working can anyone tell me how to group price using this plugin or there is anyother way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use the group name instead of the group id

Example:
if you have a customer group with ID=1 and Name=group1 use: group_price:group1

Comment: Hell, I was going to be real sad, if this would have not worked, but it worked perfectly, thanks for the help!